# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable Flask JWT

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jwt, typeerror

I'm working on a Flask server where we have a route to validate a user's JWT token using the library [flask-jwt-extended](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended). This is what our route looks like:

```
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token, create_refresh_token, get_jwt_identity, jwt_refresh_token_required
)

@app.route('/api/users/validate', methods=['POST'])
def validate_user():

    if not request.json:
        abort(400)

    data = request.get_json()

    if ('id_token' not in data):
        abort(400, "id_token must be a parameter in the JSON")

    decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(data['id_token'])

    if ('uid' not in decoded_token):
        return json.dumps({'verified': False}), 200
    else:
        user = mongo.db.users.find_one({'_id': decoded_token['uid']})

        if user:
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=user['_id'])
            refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user['_id'])
            return json.dumps({'verified': True, 'access_token': access_token, 'refresh_token': refresh_token}), 200
        else:
            return json.dumps({'verified': False, 'message': 'unable to locate user'}), 401
```

For some reason, whenever I try to make a post request to this route, I get a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error for the function `create_access_token`. Here's the stack trace:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2019 12:24:17] "POST /api/users/validate HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/src/controllers/auth_controller.py", line 44, in validate_user
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user['_id')
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/utils.py", line 157, in create_access_token
    return jwt_manager._create_access_token(identity, fresh, expires_delta, user_claims)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/jwt_manager.py", line 476, in _create_access_token
    json_encoder=config.json_encoder
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/tokens.py", line 77, in encode_access_token
    json_encoder=json_encoder)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/tokens.py", line 31, in _encode_jwt
    json_encoder=json_encoder).decode('utf-8')
  File "/Users/user/Documents/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 61, in encode
    cls=json_encoder
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've triple checked the flask-jwt-extended docs and `create_acess_token` is, in fact, a function and when printing `create_acess_token` it prints that it's a function. I've looked over almost all of the StackOverflow posts on this topic and none of them are helpful—most of them talk about user generated classes, but this is a function that I'm pulling from an external library.

Here is the definition of `create_access_token` in flask-jwt-extended:

```
def _create_access_token(self, identity, fresh=False, expires_delta=None, user_claims=None):
    if expires_delta is None:
        expires_delta = config.access_expires

    if user_claims is None:
        user_claims = self._user_claims_callback(identity)

        access_token = encode_access_token(
            identity=self._user_identity_callback(identity),
            secret=self._encode_key_callback(identity),
            algorithm=config.algorithm,
            expires_delta=expires_delta,
            fresh=fresh,
            user_claims=user_claims,
            csrf=config.csrf_protect,
            identity_claim_key=config.identity_claim_key,
            user_claims_key=config.user_claims_key,
            json_encoder=config.json_encoder
        )
        return access_token
```

If it helps, the code is in Python 3.6.5 and it's in a virtual environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us the full error traceback message, and show us the definition of `create_access_token` (presumably it's an import?)

Comment: Does this error happen on every POST call, or only sometimes?

Comment: @JohnGordon every POST call

Comment: @JohnGordon updated to include full stack trace, import, and function definition

Comment: If the problem were simply that `create_access_token` isn't a function, the error traceback would end in your view function.  But it doesn't; it keeps going for half a dozen more calls, so there's something else wrong.  It looks like the problem might be with the `config.json_encoder` item in `_create_access_token`.  Did you have to run some configuration script, or edit a config file, when you installed that module?

Comment: @JohnGordon That was exactly it! I had a custom JSONEncoder function in my server's __init__.py function that was removed accidentally and that's what was causing the encoding errors. Thank you so much.